# How to Setup oracle 11g R2 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: oracle11g, ubuntu-16.04

i'm newer on Ubuntu community  and i need to setup oracle database 11g R2 
and i try to set-up oracle i do following steps

1. downloaded oracle two archive files.
2. extracted folder and result will be database folder.
3. ./runinstaller from command line .
4. then oracle wizard appear next - > next .
5. error appear click continue multiple times.
6. then finished installed

when i try to type command sqlplus
it's tell me command not found , i try also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04) and try [here](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/archives/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits)
please any one give me help
thanks advance.

Comment: Please refer to [sqlplus: command not found on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/534546) and many more that can be found just searching *"sqlplus command not found"*.

Comment: i see error not sqlplus command not found i see setup error from first how to  setup without error ?

Comment: *error appear* is not really an answerable question. Please leave out irrelevant stuff about downloads, etc. and add information about the exact error message you get.

Comment: I am also very new to Ubuntu (although I have some rudimentary understanding of Unix). I was able to install Oracle on 16.04 by following the instructions here. There was one point where I had to edit a text file to change "16.04" to "16.04.2" (or something like that) - you will know when that is, because you will get an error in the process. Otherwise, if you follow the instructions EXACTLY as written and you don't skip any steps, it should work. It did for me.  https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/